# QGIS Attribute Table Not Displaying Data

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

Using QGIS and one minute I could see the attribute table, the next minute I couldn't. Using QGIS on Linux Mint 13. I tried purge/autoclean/reinstall to get a completely new download of all dependencies and no saved config files, but the problem persists. I can't see the attribute tables for either shapefiles or SpatiaLite data (haven't tested PostGIS yet).

Note, the underlying data *is* there. I can open the DBF in LibreOffice and see the expected data, and if I click on a feature with the Identify Features tool, I do see the attributes associated with that feature. Symbolization of the data (e.g. a simple choropleth map) also works based on the underlying data. The attribute table displays all expected columns, but no rows, as if it was a newly created completely empty layer.

This was a recent install on a new computer, but for the last week I have been able to add data and view attribute tables as expected. Today I set the configuration option to "Open attribute table in a dock window (QGIS restart required)" and then when I tried look at the attribute table, no data was displayed. I restarted QGIS, still the same. I then turned off the docking, no effect, restarted the computer, no effect. Completely reinstalled QGIS as indicated above, no effect.

One obvious gotcha is that "Show selected only" could be checked, but that is not the case here.

Has anyone run into this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under `Settings->Options->General` (a bit down the panel) I have a dropdownbox "Behaviour of Attribute table" (or whatever it is in your language).

After switching that to `"Show All Objects"`, I see them in the table. It looks like that overrides the checkbox in the attribute table itself.

Comment: Thanks, André. That is exactly right. I inadvertently changed that setting using the scroll wheel while I was setting the attribute table docking behavior in the same dialog.

Comment: In the version I am using, 2.18, this option is under, Settings -> Options -> Data sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a DB table, in the SQL editor window, click "Retrieve columns" after executing the query, otherwise it might not worrk.