# Attributes not Showing in QGIS 2.18.10

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to complete a QGIS tutorial from the documentation, but I am not seeing any attributes fields for the districts in Western_Cape_UTM33S.shp:

http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/analysis_exercise.html#find-the-correct-districts

The data are here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5evvkizuunrcs0/more_analysis.zip?dl=0

I tried the using the answer as suggested in this question, but didn't have any luck:

[QGIS Attribute Table Not Displaying Data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39365/qgis-attribute-table-not-displaying-data)

I haven't had this issue with other shapefiles thus far.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my QGIS setup or with the file itself

Comment: The file is fine. I cannot reproduce your issue in 2.18.10 on Win10.

Comment: Okay, Thanks. There must be something wrong with my setup. I'll keep playing with it and see if I can figure out what is wrong.