# Attribute table not showing data in QGIS 3.2 (prior answers only apply to QGIS 2)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-3

I've opened a .shp in QGIS 3.2.3 and there is no data in the attribute table. It shows the correct number of rows but no columns.

A previous answer recommended choosing "Show All Objects" under the "General" tab in Options, but that option does not exist in QGIS 3.2.3.

Would anyone be able to provide advice on this?

(I also tried installing QGIS 3.4 to see if that resolved the issue and that didn't work either)

EDIT:
The previous answer I refer to is [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39365/qgis-attribute-table-not-displaying-data?rq=1).

Comment: You can check if there actually is data by opening the *.dbf file with LibreOffice Calc. Once had the same issue and removing and re-adding the shapefile from my project solved this issue.

Comment: There is data in the *.dbf file, and QGIS actually shows a map. It's just the attribute table is empty.

Comment: You mention prior/previous answers but what question(s) do those come from?  Whenever you refer to previous questions or answers from this site it is helpful to include links to them so that potential answerers do not have to waste time trying to figure out what you have already looked at.

Answer (score 3):

> It shows the correct number of rows but no columns.

It seems that the columns are hidden.
Add a new column, right click on the name of the column and click on *Organize Columns...*
Ticking their names, they should be shown again.

[image: Organize Columns...]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't even create a new field. The option to do so is greyed out.

EDIT: if I create one using the field calculator and go to Organize Columns, no columns are listed.

Comment: *Toggle editing mode (Ctrl+E)* to create a new column or delete an existing. Is it possible that the table has no attributes. Once the column is created, click on *Organice columns...", if there are no columns there, it is likely that entities do not have attributes attached.

Comment: Ah, nothing showed up, so it's not there! I have a .dbf file with the shapefile's information in it, though. Is there a way to import it into the attribute table? Or should this be a new question?

Comment: Do you have the *.dbf* file at the same folder and with the same name that the *.shp* file? If so, just add a new vector layer with that *.shp* file.

Comment: They didn't have the same name! That was it, thank you so much!